# Substring and Charindex - issues with minus operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. In the column `PROJECT_NAME` I have line items, all with the same format, that look like this:

```
PROJECT_NAME
--------------
Caulk, Norman v BPI
Caulk, Norman v BWD
Carper, Robert v ECH
```

I am trying to extract the first name (second name in the text string) and am using this query:

```
select
substring(Project_name,(charindex(',',PROJECT_NAME,0)),((CHARINDEX(' v ',PROJECT_NAME)-
(charindex(',',PROJECT_NAME)))))
from RPT_PROJ_MAIN pm
```

When I run this query I get the following error:
`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

I have isolated all of the different expressions and they all work fine on their own. If I replace the minus operator with a `+` then the query runs fine and I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Strange.  Your query works fine for me.  Are you sure the one you posted here is the variation that is not working, or did you post a slightly-different one?

Comment: same one...and just to be certain I re-ran the one I posted...same result

Comment: Runs fine, but returns this for me - ", Norman", ", Robert" etc...

Comment: Lol there has to be something different about the field `project_name` that is not affecting you guys as it is me. Any thoughts on what that might be? `PROJECT_NAME(varchar(250),null)`

Comment: And these are the only three values? Are you sure there isn't a value in there that doesn't contain a `,` or `... v ...`? `SELECT * FROM dbo.RPT_PROJ_MAIN WHERE CHARINDEX(',', PROJECT_NAME) = 0 OR CHARINDEX(' v ', PROJECT_NAME) = 0;`

Comment: One Column: `PROJECT_NAME`

Comment: Sorry, I said columns but I meant values. Edited.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand... with the edit I see what you mean now and you were right. Should have posted as an answer :-) But thanks a lot regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that despite you saying that **all** rows have the same format some of them don't.

Specifically if a value has no `v <something>` at the end you'll get exactly that error, because the third parameter to `SUBSTRING()` function will have a negative value

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49751e/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solution for this just used below mentioned trick to handle this issue. Require to Declare value you want to minus. Just see the example below.

Declare @Val numeric=2
PRINT LEFT('My Name is Bhumesh Shah',charindex('is','My Name is Bhumesh Shah'))
PRINT LEFT('My Name is Bhumesh Shah',charindex('is','My Name is Bhumesh Shah')-@val)

Output:
My Name i
My Name